# How to do a mini calculator using a single event Listener instead of onclick events in each button?

Tags: javascript, events

The challenge is to do a simple mini calculator with one input, 4 buttons, and an output. 
The input is to add a number that will appear in the output immediately, next I will choose one of the four buttons (+,-,*,/)to do the math and next write again another number on the input. In the output will appear the result of that operation, further will continuing to do maths by clicking again in the buttons and add another number, and actualizing always the result.

I have done this before with onclick event in each button and using a prompt to write the numbers. now I want to use an input to write the numbers and using one event listener to all the buttons. Can anybody help me with the solution and explain to me each step?

This is my code so far :

```
let input =document.querySelector('#input');
let output =document.querySelector('#output');
let divButtons = document.querySelector('#buttons');


let messageOutput = (message) =>{
   output.innerHTML = message;
}

messageOutput(input.value); // this doesn't work. What I miss to do show the input in the output?


divButtons.addEventListener('click', () =>{
 //do something

})
```

```
<section class="container">

  <h1 class="heading">Do some maths</h1>

  <div class="calculator">

  <input class="inputNumbers" id="input" type="number" placeholder="choose a number here">

  <div class="buttons" id="buttons">
       <button id="plus" class="btn btn-plus">+</button>
       <button id="minus" class="btn btn-minus">-</button>
       <button id="multiply" class="btn btn-multiply">*</button>
       <button id="divide" class="btn btn-divide">/</button>
 </div>

 <div id="output" class="visor"></div>
 </div>

</section>
```

I am new so I need help to solve this challenge and understand what should I have to do. 
Thank you

Comment: If your question is answered, why you are not closing the bounty?

Comment: After the bounty ends, there is a grace period of 24 hours to manually award the bounty. Simply click the bounty award icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty to the answerer.

Comment: already done that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modified JS code a bit, using the listener you already wrote, let me know if you need more explaining. Hope it helps.

```js
let input =document.querySelector('#input');
let output =document.querySelector('#output');
let divButtons = document.querySelector('#buttons');

let a = null;
let b = null;
let op = null;

let messageOutput = (message) =>{
   output.innerHTML = message;
}

messageOutput(input.value); // this doesn't work. What I miss to do show the input in the output?


divButtons.addEventListener('click', (event) =>{
 //checking if button is pressed
 if(event.target.type = 'submit') {
  //if a is not set before, meaning first time input
  if(a == null) {
    a = Number(input.value);
  } else {
    // second number
    b = Number(input.value);
    if(op == 'plus') {
      a += b;
    } else if(op == 'minus') {
      a -= b;
    }else if(op == 'multiply') {
      a *= b;
    } else {
      a /= b;
    }
  }
  //saving the operator that was pressed
  op = event.target.id;
  //showing output
  output.innerHTML = a + " " + op;

  //resetting input on each button pressed.
  input.value = '';
 }
});
```

```html
<section class="container">

  <h1 class="heading">Do some maths</h1>

  <div class="calculator">

  <input class="inputNumbers" id="input" type="number" placeholder="choose a number here">

  <div class="buttons" id="buttons">
       <button id="plus" class="btn btn-plus">+</button>
       <button id="minus" class="btn btn-minus">-</button>
       <button id="multiply" class="btn btn-multiply">*</button>
       <button id="divide" class="btn btn-divide">/</button>
 </div>

 <div id="output" class="visor"></div>
 </div>

</section>
```

Comment: I apologise if you felt that way sir. I am also new here. Maybe I just over stepped here.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps. Modified your snippet a little and added a few variables.

```
let input = document.querySelector("#input");
let output = document.querySelector("#output");
let divButtons = document.querySelector("#buttons");

let result = null;
let selectedOperation = null;

let messageOutput = message => {
  output.innerHTML = message;
};

divButtons.addEventListener("click", event => {
  //do something
  let id = event.target.id;
  let value = parseInt(input.value);

  switch (selectedOperation) {
    case "plus":
      result += value;
      break;

    case "minus":
      result -= value;
      break;

    case "multiply":
      result *= value;
      break;

    case "divide":
      result /= value;
      break;

    default:
      result = value;
      break;
  }

  selectedOperation = id;
  input.value = "";
  messageOutput(`${result} ${selectedOperation}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Save your input number into a variable, then save the math function clicked by the user into a variable, then apply it to the saved input number using the current value the user has input as the factor.

Something like this:

```js
let input = document.querySelector('#input');
let output = document.querySelector('#output');
let inputnumber = 0;
let subtotal = 0;
let total = 0;
let calculate = 0;
let x;
let y;
input.oninput = (e) => {
    if(subtotal == 0) {
        output.value = e.target.value;
    }
    x = Number(e.target.value);
    y = Number(subtotal);
    switch (calculate) {
        case "btn-divide":
        calc = y / x;
        break;
        case "btn-multiply":
        calc = y * x;
        break;
        case "btn-plus":
        calc =  x + y;
        break;
        case "btn-minus":
        calc = y - x;
        break;
        case 0:
        calc = x;
        break;
    }
    output.value = calc;
}
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('#buttons');
divs.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', event => {
    calculate = event.target.classList[1];
    input.value = null;
    subtotal = calc;
}));
```

```html
<section class="container">

  <h1 class="heading">Do some maths</h1>

  <div class="calculator">

  <input class="inputNumbers" id="input" type="number" placeholder="choose a number here">
  
  <div class="buttons" id="buttons">
       <button id="plus" class="btn btn-plus">+</button>
       <button id="minus" class="btn btn-minus">-</button>
       <button id="multiply" class="btn btn-multiply">*</button>
       <button id="divide" class="btn btn-divide">/</button>
 </div>

 <input id="output" type="number" class="visor" value=0>
 </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Can you explain to me this part? what is oninput after input :   input.oninput = (e) => { (...)
Thank you

Comment: It's binding an event listener to the input element which fires every time the value of the input changes and runs the code within the curly braces

Comment: I am still confused. you have here two events oninput and an addeventListener in the el. that is it?  but why using oninput instead of an addEventListener to that input also?

Comment: It's just two different ways you can add an event listener

Comment: yes, but what I wanted is to use just a single Event Listener and not using the old way. I said that.

Comment: but you said "The input is to add a number that will appear in the output immediately". In order to achieve that you need an event listener on the input, not just the buttons

Comment: "How to do a mini calculator using a single event Listener instead of onclick events in each button?"  <- This is what I said . Then I described what I've been doing.  What I want is to grab the values from the input and output somewhere of course. But my thing is to use one Event Listener to all the buttons  and show the result since I add the second number  a + b = a(result) + b = a(result) + b = a(result) .  I just dont want to use events in old way .

Answer (score 0):

Term you are looking for is called event delegation.

```js
let input =document.querySelector('#input');
let output =document.querySelector('#output');
let divButtons = document.querySelector('#buttons');


let messageOutput = (message) =>{
   output.innerHTML = message;
}

messageOutput(input.value); // this doesn't work. What I miss to do show the input in the output?


divButtons.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
 console.log(e.target.id)

})
```

```html
<section class="container">

  <h1 class="heading">Do some maths</h1>

  <div class="calculator">

  <input class="inputNumbers" id="input" type="number" placeholder="choose a number here">

  <div class="buttons" id="buttons">
       <button id="plus" class="btn btn-plus">+</button>
       <button id="minus" class="btn btn-minus">-</button>
       <button id="multiply" class="btn btn-multiply">*</button>
       <button id="divide" class="btn btn-divide">/</button>
 </div>

 <div id="output" class="visor"></div>
 </div>

</section>
```

Basically you do not attach event listeners on every element, but you attach same event on parent of all elements and you can track the source of event using e.target.

Comment: yes I know that, but I need how I do it . I need the solution and explained.

Comment: You can take actually two inputs using two input fields. Whenever any button is clicked, compute a*b where * is any of +, -, *, /. There is no exact answer here. It totally depends on your requirements.

Comment: the challenge is only one input. because it supposes to continuing doing the math ., not a+b but instead the result with next number upgrading. yes I know there isn't one answer , I just wanted someone to show me one of many answers. but ok. I will wait for someone gives me a proper answer.thanks